# Помогите реализовать SQL запрос на случайную выборку по нескольким типам полей

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть такая таблица

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
| 1  | 1    |
+----+------+
| 2  | 1    |
+----+------+
| 3  | 1    |
+----+------+
| 4  | 2    |
+----+------+
| 5  | 2    |
+----+------+
| 6  | 2    |
+----+------+
```

необходимо сделать выборку одного случайного значения по указанным типам.
Т.е. если я указываю `WHERE type IN(1,2[,...])` то в условии должны делаться случайные выборки поля `id` по каждому типу. Каждый раз должны быть случайные значения поля `id`, например согласно условию `WHERE type IN(1,2[,...])`, могут быть значения `[1,4]` или `[1,5]` или `[3,5]` и т.д. На один указанный тип одна случайная запись.

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE type IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Конечно запрос неправильный, но мне на ум ничего не приходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что нужно для каждой группы вернуть одну случайную запись из этой группы, то

```
SELECT ( SELECT t2.id 
         FROM `table` t2 
         WHERE t2.type=t1.type 
         ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
       ) id, type
FROM `table` t1
GROUP BY type
```

Ну и - для этого запроса на более-менее пухлой таблице почти критически необходим индекс по type.

Comment: То что нужно. Ходил вокруг до около со вложенным запросом, не подумал реализовать через синонимы, как у тебя. Спасибо!

Comment: @ChaikinEvgenii Не понял, к какому боку тут приложить слово "синоним". А так - обычный коррелированный подзапрос...

Comment: Название каждой таблицы ты присваиваешь синонимы, а уже в подзапросе ты используешь доступ к данным по синониму. По крайней мере я думаю что так работает )

Comment: @ChaikinEvgenii не синоним, а псевдоним (алиас, alias). Но это как бы догма - если более одной таблицы, то везде алиасы.